# Why the code inside onComplete does not execute?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I follow Firebase Docs to design a register and login system, I find the code inside onComplete does not execute.However, the register function can be executed. Why this happend, and what should I change?
Thanks!

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    // create new user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        //FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                    } else {

                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
    // [END create_user_with_email]
}
```

Comment: Have you verified if the user gets created in Firebase?
If not, add... addOnFailureListener() and addOnCanceledListener() and log the message either of them give you to understand why

Comment: "I find the code inside onComplete does not execute" How did you determine that?

Comment: Yes, user can be created in Firebase. So I think there should be a log "createUserWithEmail:success" or "createUserWithEmail:failure", but I didn't get any of them.

Comment: How did you check that `onComplete()` is not triggered.  Please edit your question and show us in code. Please respond with @AlexMamo